# Is it possible to determine what a wireless access point needs?

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, dhclient

I am trying to connect to an unsecured wireless access point using a Raspberry Pi and Edimax 802.11n USB WiFi adapter.  From a fresh install of the latest Raspbian image (Jessie), I am able to see the various SSIDs available; however I cannot connect to any of them.

Looking at the output of dmesg, I see:

> rtw_wx_set_mlme
>   rtw_wx_set_mlme, cmd=0, reason=3
>   when trying to connect to the SSID (let's call it 'guest').

Running `dhclient -v wlan0` results in several entries of

> DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval x
>   where x is some integer <= 20.  Eventually I get an error that "no DHCPOFFERS received".

I suspect this issue is related to what the RPi is sending in the DHCPDISCOVER and what my institution's WAP wants in order to provide an offer because:

- The same RPi with the same configuration can connect to my home wireless
- The RPi can connect to the wired network at my institution without a problem.
- I can connect to the wireless at my institution with other devices (android, Windows laptop, ...)

I've pretty much exhausted the "solutions" provided on the first 1-2 pages of web searches for "rtw_wx_set_mlme, cmd=0, reason=3" and "No DHCPOFFERS received." (in particular [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1371247)) with no noticeable progress.

Given that I have access to computers that can connect to the wireless and the RPi, **how can I figure out why the RPi and WAP don't play nice together**?

Comment: You might try going into `wpa_cli` directly, if that's provided; might give a better idea of the requirements, or more control over how it connects.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not need to register the wifi MAC address with your institution? We do it here with a couple of networks. No registered/authorized MAC, no IP address given by the DHCP service.

Comment: I have never attempted to register the MAC with any of the other devices that have been able to connect to the guest AP, so I don't think this is the issue.